# Why Can't I Strip This Character From A String?

Tags: string, elixir

Elixir 1.0, Erlang 17.3 on Windows 7 x64.

I type this code:

```
l = "[9,0]"
s = String.strip(l,"[")
```

And I get this:

> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in String.lstrip/2
>       (elixir) lib/string.ex:527: String.lstrip("[9,0]", "[")
>       (elixir) lib/string.ex:564: String.strip/2

What am I missing?

I also tried `s = String.strip(l,",")` and same error. Also tried `s = String.strip(l,'[')` same error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass a character to `String.strip/2`:

```
s = String.strip(l, ?[)
```

As Shashidhar points out in a comment, `String.strip/2` has been dropped from Elixir documentation and may be removed completely in future. The suggested replacement is [String.trim/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#trim/2) which takes a String as its second argument:

```
s = String.trim(l, "[")
```

Comment: String.strip/2 API has been deprecated.
Info : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38073411/3142192

Answer (score 4):

You should use a single char as a second param, not a string.

```
iex(42)> l = "[9,0]"             
"[9,0]"
iex(43)> s = String.strip(l, ?[) 
"9,0]"
iex(44)> s = String.strip(l, ?])
"[9,0"
```

See more in the [String.strip/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.1.0/String.html#strip/2) docs (deprecated in Elixir 1.2, to be replaced by [String.trim](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#trim/2)).

Comment: You know I saw that documentation but didn't pay close enough attention.  I  was trying "? ["  (although I didn't mention it in the question).