# What does ? do in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am aware of `String.strip/2`, but I cannot figure out its usage for removing whitespaces.

```
String.strip "_some_", ?_   #=> "some"
```

If the string had whitespaces instead of _, how does one strip them? Also, it would be great if someone can explain what ? means here.

Comment: For the reference of others who may find this question: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/String.html#strip/1

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047715/why-cant-i-strip-this-character-from-a-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's `String.strip/1` which strips all unicode whitespace. So you can just

```
iex(2)> String.strip("\t\ntest   ")
"test"
```

Comment: Awesome. Do you happen to know what ? means here? Any documentation reference would help.

Comment: Looking at iex it seems to mean a codepoint, for example `?\s #=> 32` and you can even `String.strip(" test ", 32)`. I actually assumed it means a one-char String - `?a` being a shorthand for `"a"` which would be a direct port of the ruby syntax.

Answer (score 48):

The question mark preceding a character returns its codepoint, it's mentioned in the [Unicode and Code Points](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#unicode-and-code-points) section of the getting started guide:

> In Elixir you can use a `?` in front of a character literal to reveal its code point:
>
> ```elixir
> iex> ?a
> 97
> iex> ?ł
> 322
> ```

Comment: And to strip simple whitespaces one can simply do `?\s`. We should probably add such examples to the documentation. :)