# What does the "?" operator do in Elixir?

Tags: unicode, elixir, operators, codepoint

The [Ecto source code](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/e81fa35092bfe078883398641adb8aa7763a3e54/lib/ecto/uuid.ex#L60-L82) makes use of expressions `?0`, `?1`, etc.  You can see how they evaluate:

```
iex(14)> ?0
48
iex(15)> ?1
49
iex(16)> ?2
50
```

What does that mean though?  This is very hard to search for.  What does the `?<character>` actually do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does ? do in Elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995608/what-does-do-in-elixir)

Answer (score 4):

From:  https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#unicode-and-code-points

> In Elixir you can use a ? in front of a character literal to reveal its code point:

If you aren't familiar with [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point):

> Unicode organizes all of the characters in its repertoire into code charts, and each character is given a unique numerical index. This numerical index is known as a Code Point.

The `?<character>` can also be used in interesting ways for [pattern matching](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/bdcf887afe89905e3db5f25ad0164d466d09aa5e/lib/elixir/lib/float.ex#L140) and [guard clauses](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/bdcf887afe89905e3db5f25ad0164d466d09aa5e/lib/elixir/lib/float.ex#L131).

```
  defp parse_unsigned(<<digit, rest::binary>>) when digit in ?0..?9,
    do: parse_unsigned(rest, false, false, <<digit>>)

  ...

  defp parse_unsigned(<<?., digit, rest::binary>>, false, false, acc) when digit in ?0..?9,
    do: parse_unsigned(rest, true, false, <<acc::binary, ?., digit>>)
```

The [Elixir docs on it](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/syntax-reference.html#integers-in-other-bases-and-unicode-code-points) also clarify that it is only syntax.  As @sabiwara points out:

> Those constructs exist only at the syntax level. `quote do: ?A` just returns `65` and doesn't show any `?` operator

As @Everett noted in the comments, there is a helpful package called [`Xray`](https://hexdocs.pm/xray/Xray.html#content) that provides some handy utility functions to help understand what's happening.

For example [`Xray.codepoint(some_char)`](https://hexdocs.pm/xray/Xray.html#codepoint/2) can do what `?<char>` does but it works for variables whereas `?` only works with literals.  [`Xray.codepoints(some_string)`](https://hexdocs.pm/xray/Xray.html#codepoints/2) will do the whole string.

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question, but I thought I would add a link to https://hexdocs.pm/xray/ -- it was only when investigating strings in Elixir that I finally grokked encodings, and the Xray package was a useful study.

Comment: Thanks @Everett !  I'm not blown away by the docs for xray, but it definitely sounds interesting.  Any quick tips on how to use it?  EDIT:  It was a little hard to find, but there are actually some docs:  https://hexdocs.pm/xray/Xray.html#content  That's useful enough I think I'll add it to the answer

Comment: I think it is interesting to also mention the official documentation about this: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/syntax-reference.html#integers-in-other-bases-and-unicode-code-points. Especially this part: `Those constructs exist only at the syntax level`. `quote do: ?A` just returns `65` and doesn't show any `?` operator.

Comment: @Freedom_Ben thanks for including Xray in the answer! I tried to add explanations and examples to every function in there, but any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: @Everett I wanted to show a screenshot of my suggestion, but since can't do that here on SO I just opened an issue:  https://github.com/fireproofsocks/xray/issues/3

Comment: I responded in the Github issue (w a new version), but the TL;DR: it pays to get familiar with navigating the Hex docs: most of the goodies are visible when you click on a specific module.