# Elixir 1.3.0: String.strip/1 and String.strip/2 API documentation missing.

Tags: elixir

It seems that Elixir 1.3.0 doesn't show anymore the documentation for String.strip/1 and String.strip/2:

```
iex(1)> h String.strip
No documentation for String.strip was found
```

they are missing also in the current online documentation (v1.3, Master, Stable), but the functions are still recognized by the compiler:

```
iex(2)> String.strip("   Hallo, World!   ")
"Hallo, World!"
```

So I'm wondering if this is just a bug in String documentation, or if these functions are going to become deprecated. I can't find any better information googling.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These functions have been soft deprecated. This means they have been marked as `@doc false`. Currently the plan is to [deprecate with warnings by 1.5](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/b98b4bd235ccf461c49d7218a9614d34df94bfdb/lib/elixir/lib/string.ex#L591).

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.3/CHANGELOG.md#3-soft-deprecations-no-warnings-emitted

> [String] The confusing String.strip/2, String.lstrip/2 and String.rstrip/2 API has been soft deprecated in favor of String.trim/2, String.trim_leading/2 and String.trim_trailing/2